# Intel Altera MAX 10 DEV KIT Interface - Can a RS232 6 pin PMOD module by Digilent be used seamlessly with MAX 10 for PC-FPGA UART communication?

Tags: rs232, intel-fpga, intel, max10

I am planning to either purchase a MAX 10 or a DE2-115 dev kit to implement communication via both ethernet and RS-232. DE2-115 has both ports soldered onto the board, but MAX-10 has 2 ethernet ports only. On its specs, it says that one can attach a 12-pin Digilent Pmod module to its 12 pin Pmod port. But, the Digilent RS-232 Pmod module states that it can be connected to a board having "6pin UART enabled Pmod port". All I need to know, is whether that module will work with the MAX 10 dev board or not. Am in a situation where any help is great help. I would really appreciate if anyone is familiar with what I'm talking about.

Max 10 - https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/programmable/products/boards_and_kits/dev-kits/altera/max-10-fpga-development-kit.html

RS-232 Pmod BY Digilent - https://store.digilentinc.com/pmod-rs232-serial-converter-and-interface-standard/

Comment: There is no reason why it shouldn't work if you write the VHDL/Verilog code for the interface. Have you checked with Digilent?

Comment: @LeonHeller Yeah. They say that its built to be used with Digilent Dev boards, and are not sure if it will work with MAX 10 dev board. They also claim that they weren't aware of it's mention on altera's website. I agree with you, but after reading what Digilent has to say, I don't want to take a risk. I wanted to know thoughts on this, by experts like you, as I am relatively inexperienced in this field.

Answer (score 1):

@Sid, the referenced PMOD PCB is a level translator. It will convert the CMOS (3v3) voltage levels on the Altera MAX-10 to RS232 compliant voltage levels. Respectively, your PC interface must be also of RS232 levels (NOT 3v3 voltage swings!!) to interface with this PMOD. Having said this, your MAX 10 or whatever FPGA you wish to use must offer 2 GPIO pins for your UART IP. One for TX (transmitter) and another for RX (receiver) to the outside world through this PMOD. You will supply the voltage @ +3v3 and ground from your MAX 10 to power this bridge transceiver and send away. As long as your UART IP is framing at the same speed and format (ie. 9600,N,8,1) using say Teraterm on your PC and your IP is fine on the MAX 10, you will have communication. To keep it simple, DISABLE hardware flow control so that you do not need to wire up the RTS or CTS lines. Check out fpga4fun.com website which details some great Verilog code examples for UART, etc.

Please review this webpage for the details of this PMOD RS232 transceiver:

https://reference.digilentinc.com/reference/pmod/pmodrs232/reference-manual

@Leon - great to see you here - a true legend and have seen your countless posts and also on the xcore.com forum :)